# Can we use FireBase cloud Messaging to send or receive messages or both ways using C++ on Windows Desktop/Console or Linux console appliction?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

After building FirebaseCloudMessaging Sample [Application](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-cpp/tree/master/messaging/testapp/src/desktop)  on Windows Using Visual studio 2015, Setting appOptions using C++, It says "Initialized Firbase Cloud Messaging" But I don't see FCM token available to communicate.

Answer (score 8):

The Firebase C++ libraries are specifically designed to be used in iOS and Android apps.

The first line of the [sample project's readme](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-cpp) explains that as:

> iOS and Android samples for the Firebase C++ SDK.

And the first line of the [documentation of the Firebase C++ SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup):

> The Firebase C++ SDK provides a C++ interface on top of Firebase for iOS and Android.

So while the sample apps may compile on other platforms, the underlying infrastructure they need to work is not available on those platforms.