# Using Firebase Cloud Messaging with Windows Application

Tags: javascript, android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use Firebase Cloud Messaging with my android and iOS app, however I have also a windows / Mac OS version of this app and I would like to keep the same logic. I know that Firebase Cloud Messaging can work with website via Javascript, so is there any way I can follow to make my windows application to work with this javascript version of Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Comment: There is no client SDK for Firebase Cloud Messaging on Windows. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229503/can-we-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-to-send-or-receive-messages-or-both-ways-usi