# How to configure a Firestore connection using FireSharp in a WinForm App

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, fire-sharp

All the reference material that I find online is using FireSharp to configure a connection with Firebase's Realtime Database. Further, I cannot find the **AuthSecret** and **BasePath** for my Firestore as the current viable use suggested by Firebase is the AdminSDK. Can anyone mention how to use AdminSDK and FireSharp to connect with Firestore. [Here](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp) is the reference/example I found:

```
IFirebaseConfig config = new FirebaseConfig
  {
     AuthSecret = "your_firebase_secret",
     BasePath = "https://yourfirebase.firebaseio.com/"
  };
```

This is what I found in my Firebase Console:
[image]

Comment: Please check out the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1kqj7sWDslY starts from 1:27 for the steps to access the database secrets from Firebase's latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I have found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61248834/using-firesharp-for-windows-desktop-push-notifications-only?rq=1#:%7E:text=The%20FireSharp%20library%20that%20you%20use%20only%20wraps%20the%20Firebase%20Realtime%20Database%20API%20as%20far%20as%20I%20see). FireSharp only wraps the Firebase Realtime Database API.