# Is that possible for Win32/64 application to receive push notification message from Firebase?

Tags: windows, delphi, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is that possible for window application to receive push notification message from Firebase? If yes, how it works?

Comment: There is no SDK for receiving Firebase Cloud Messaging messages in Windows. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229503/can-we-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-to-send-or-receive-messages-or-both-ways-usi

Answer (score 4):

No, firbase is only available for android/ios and javascript. javascript mean that in some way we can play in win32/64 system, but you will need to analyze the javascript protocole to emulate it inside your win32/64 software. Maybe a more easy way will be to use somethink like node.JS inside your software to emulate a browser and javascript

Comment: is there any work around and sample?

Comment: Yes you can use Azure Notification Hub