# Can FCM push notifications in Electron App

Tags: firebase, winforms, electron, firebase-cloud-messaging, electron-packager

I'm trying to send notifications from **Firebase Cloud Messaging** (FCM) to a **window app** (window form for example) but it doesn't seem to be possible (since fcm only supports android/ios/webapp, for [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/fcm-architecture) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43233892/6284714)).

So trying building **Electron app** to be able to receive and display notifications from fcm (slack is built from electron js and also displays notifications, [here](https://www.electronjs.org/apps/slack)), and found the **[electron-push-receiver](https://github.com/MatthieuLemoine/electron-push-receiver)** allowing it to receive notifications from FCM

But it seems that there is no update for a long time, so there is a [issue#80](https://github.com/MatthieuLemoine/electron-push-receiver/issues/80)

Now is it possible to build electron application that can receive notifications from FCM?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I just implemented FCM in my Electron app earlier today by following the guide here:
https://github.com/CydeSwype/electron-fcm-demo

[Screenshot of FCM working in an Electron app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajpTj.png)

I was skeptical at first as well, given that the repo hasn't been updated in a while, but was pleasantly surprised that it still works.
If you have any further questions, go ahead and I'll try to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I also got this working with electron-push-receiver, though I had to do [a workaround for more recent versions of Electron](https://github.com/MatthieuLemoine/electron-push-receiver/issues/86).

I looked at the `firebase-admin.messaging` Node package but that is only for privileged environments.

The HTTP 503 issue you linked it seems was just another outage that has been resolved; I can still register for push notifications with this setup.